# How can you see if kernel symbols are hidden?

Tags: linux, python-2.7, linux-kernel

I am trying to use python to see if Kernel symbols are hidden. I understand the basics of the nm module, and so far I have only used a few commands and I am now kind of stuck. Is there a default setting that I can check to find this information?

So far, I have just been looking at the external and exported types using `nm -u` and reading the `/proc/kallsyms` module, but its not returning the information that I need which is to see if the symbols are truly hidden. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you mean by saying hidden symbols? Please show some examples of what you have and what you need. If you have kernel debuginfo (enabled by `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO` or installed with `-debuginfo` or `-dbg` packages), you may try to check corresponding vmlinux file (i.e. in openSUSE 13.2 it is `/usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-3.16.7-7-desktop.debug`)

Comment: It seems that he means unexported symbols

Comment: I am talking about all three levels of the symbols. I do understand that some of them are considered global (exported) while others can be considered local (external) and static. Initially i was using this as a [guideline](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Grsecurity/Appendix/Grsecurity_and_PaX_Configuration_Options#Hide_kernel_symbols) however i cannot use grsecurity for what I am attempting to do.